# Set x-axis timeline of render timechart in OMS or Application Insights

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, oms

I am using a query like this in OMS,
SecurityEvent
| where TimeGenerated > ago(4h)
| summarize count() by Activity, bin(TimeGenerated, 5min)
| render timechart

The chart displays the data correctly, however the graph data points are cramped into the end of the graph (See screenshot) whereas most of the graph is left blank (coz im retrieving data points for last 4hrs only) .
This mostly defeats the purpose of be using bin 5min as i cannot clearly see the swings in data.

The issue seems to be that by default the timeline chart uses a 24h x-axis bar.
How do i make the x-axis scale shorter so that the data is rendered more clearly. I want to implement this within the query as it is needed for creating a dashboard.
The advanced analytics page seems to do a better job of this one, see screenshot2.

[image: OMS Query page render of timechart]

[image: Advanced Analytics Page Render of Timechart]

Comment: It looks like that Application Insights/Analytics show a chart correctly. And OMS view still reserves a view for the whole day which makes it hard to look at last 4 hours. Is this correct?

Comment: yes. correct. I want my OMS dashboards to show charts like Application Insights/ Advanced Analytics does